# Justify the "Abstract" in iEEE Transaction computer society

Tags: miktex, templates, ieeetran, journal

How to justify (both left and right) the abstract in IEEETrans ?
when I generate the pdf using the standard template provided by ieee computer society transaction, I get the abstract in the left justified form.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: Do not bother about layout of a journal unless you are the graphic designer the journal hired to take care of the layout. Just use the template the journal provides.

Or look out for a journal with a layout you like.

Thhe following piece of code is for academic purpose only, and it is not advised to be used in a real document.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@IEEEtitleabstractindextextbox#1{\parbox{0.922\textwidth}{#1}}
\makeatother
```